# Loop through Type Parameter for Members and values

Tags: kotlin

```
class DoStuff<T>{
  performAction(args: T){
   //expecting T to be a data class e.g (data class Person(var info: String, var age: Int)
    //Can i loop the args without knowing the intended data class for e.g with known class i could just
    Person::java.class.members.forEach { prop -> log(args.prop)}
  }
}
```

How can I loop with the Type parameter class like

```
T::java.class.members.forEach{}
```

Comment: Keyword for your searches is “reflection”.